# Continue with the interviews?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, new-job, job-change, job-acceptance

I was actively looking for a job change and 2 weeks back accepted an offer. I'm satisfied with the offered salary and after a long discussion, the expectations from the position. I'm currently serving my notice period.

However, I'm still receiving calls for interviews but I decline them stating that I've already accepted another offer. For this I've received arguments like "you can use this as a leverage to ask for more", "why are you declining, you should continue. Maybe it's better", etc.

Is it ethical/professional to continue with the interviews?

If it helps, the locality is Bangalore, India.

Comment: Unless you're already a senior, high-flyer, I would **stick with the current plan**.  Note that recruiters *make money when they place you*, so of course they are rudely telling you what they think you should do.  (What else do you expect really?)  **Stick with the current plan.** After six months, sure, make another change for more money again!  Great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it ethical/professional to continue with the interviews?

In my opinion, the point of no return is **when you accept an offer**.  Since you have accepted an offer and are working through the notice period, you have committed to go to work for a company already.  That company has stopped looking for a person to fill the opening and are preparing for you to come on board.

Also, **playing companies against each other after you have already accepted from one company is risky** and could back fire on you.  I have actually seen where a buddy of mine tried to play to companies against each other for more money and both companies retracted their offers leaving him to start over.

Short answer, **no** it's not professional.  If something was not right about the offer you probably should not have accepted it to begin with.

Answer (score 5):

You can go ahead and interview for two reasons according to me

1. Just for the sake of experience and gauge yourself and your market value.
2. Have a possible back-up lead if your primary offer does not work out for some reason. (Like the company rescinded the offer or something)

In either case, you are at a risk if the fact you are interviewing is leaked to your new employer by some or the other means. You would have already made a poor impression before starting.

Also, as mentioned by Mr. Positive, using the offer from third company to negotiate is a very bad idea and can fireback. Also it is unprofessional.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I would go even further and say if the new company presents a truly compelling offer, it might be best to rescind acceptance of the previous one as soon as possible. When it comes to hiring, individuals are often pressured to make decisions before they're truly ready. It could leave a bad impression but it is better to renege before even starting than to stay for short time and then leave.

Comment: Actually this is an excellent point.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in using multiple offers to negotiate for better salaries. If they truly want you they should be ready to pay you what you're truly worth, since you might be the rare property to vie for out there. However trying to negotiate after already **accepting** the offer, as mentioned by Mister Positive, is clearly a bad idea.